# Почему не работает код? error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, компиляция, build-error

```
public class happy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);
        int first, second, result;
        System.out.print("Enter first num: ");
        first = num.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second num: ");
        second = num.nextInt();
        result = first + second;
        System.out.println("It is" + result + "!!!");
    }
}
```

```
happy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);
                ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class happy
happy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class happy
2 errors
```

Comment: Я его только что запустил и у меня все заработало. Чтобы избегать такой путаницы выкладывайте также сообщение компилятора об ошибке.

Comment: happy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);
                ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class happy
happy.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Scanner num = new Scanner (System.in);
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class happy
2 errors

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Answer (score 3):

Может, класс Scanner не импортировался?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, вообще-то именно это ответом и является.

Comment: @Bakhuss не может, а точно не хватает строчки import java.util.Scanner;